# HL7 C# - Receiving an ACK Response from Server

Tags: c#, tcpclient, hl7

I have created a simple client to send HL7 formatted messages to a server.  Unfortunately I do not have access to the server to see how the messages are coming in and what is being sent back.  Right now my message sends but when I wait for a message back (ACK), it just sits there waiting.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
try {
    using (var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("10.25.60.8", 10000);

        using (Stream stm = client.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] ba = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(segment1 + segment2 + segment3 + segment4 + segment5);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("MessageSend reading response");

            byte[] bb = new byte[1000];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

This is how I create the message segments:

```
clnt p = new clnt();
patientAdmit r = new patientAdmit();

r.admitMessage = "MSH|^~\\&|MP|M1|MP|M2|201701011500||ADT^A01|HL7MSG00001|P|2.3|EVN|A01|201701011500||PID|||MRN222222||TEST^MICHAEL||19890101|M||C|1 MP STREET^^MARK^ON^L4C|GL|(416)123-1234|(647)123-1234|||||||NK1|1|TEST^BARBARA|WIFE||||||NK^NEXT OF KIN|PV1|1|I|20^201^01||||123456^TEST^DOC|||SUR||||ADM|A0|";

string vt = Convert.ToChar(11).ToString();
string cr = Convert.ToChar(13).ToString();
string fs = Convert.ToChar(28).ToString();

int startSegment2 = p.GetNthIndex(r.admitMessage, Convert.ToChar("|"), 12) + 1;

int startSegment3 = p.GetNthIndex(r.admitMessage, Convert.ToChar("|"), 16) + 1;
int startSegment4 = p.GetNthIndex(r.admitMessage, Convert.ToChar("|"), 16 + 21) + 1;

int startSegment5 = p.GetNthIndex(r.admitMessage, Convert.ToChar("|"), 16 + 21 + 10) + 1;

string segment1 = vt + r.admitMessage.Substring(0, startSegment2);

string segment2 = cr + r.admitMessage.Substring(startSegment2, startSegment3 - startSegment2);

string segment3 = cr + r.admitMessage.Substring(startSegment3, startSegment4 - startSegment3);

string segment4 = cr + r.admitMessage.Substring(startSegment4, startSegment5 - startSegment4);

string segment5 = cr + r.admitMessage.Substring(startSegment5, r.admitMessage.Length - startSegment5) + cr + fs;
```

Comment: The message you send should be wrapped in the [MLLP envelope](https://blog.interfaceware.com/common-hl7-transports/)

Comment: I think, you made a server. Its confused with hl7, beacuse they had called server to who send and client to who receive

Comment: How did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a server with most HL7 Editors.  For example, grab the free trial of [HL7 soup](http://www.hl7soup.com) from their website, and create a new receiver on your desired port.
When you send in your messages they will respond straight back with an ACK message generated from your message.
In the reciever settings, you can even force the response to be an error or reject ACK so you can test your client.